# Matplotlib: how to plot clusters with different colors and annotations?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The Matplotlib is highly confusing to me. I have a `pd.DataFrame` with columns `x`,`y` an `cluster`. I wish to plot this data on an x-y plot, where every cluster has a different color and an annotation of which cluster that is.

I'm capable of doing these separately. To plot the data with different colors:

```
for c in np.unique(data['cluster'].tolist()):
    df = data[data['c'].isin([c])]
    plt.plot(df['x'].tolist(),df['y'].tolist(),'o')
plt.show()
```

This yields:

[image]

And annotations:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = df['x'].tolist()
y = df['y'].tolist()
ax.scatter(x, y)
for i, txt in enumerate(data['cluster'].tolist()):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))
plt.show()
```

This yields:

[image]

How do I combine the two? I don't understand how to mix the `figure`/`axes`/`plot` APIs all together..

---

**Sample data:**

```
pd.DataFrame({'c': ['News',   'Hobbies & Interests',   'Arts & Entertainment',   'Internal Use',   'Business',   'Internal Use',   'Internal Use',   'Ad Impression Fraud',   'Arts & Entertainment',   'Adult Content',   'Arts & Entertainment',   'Internal Use',   'Internal Use',   'Reference',   'News',   'Shopping',   'Food & Drink',   'Internal Use',   'Internal Use',   'Reference'],  
'x': [-95.44078826904297,   127.71454620361328,   -491.93121337890625,   184.5579071044922,   -191.46273803710938,   95.22545623779297,   272.2229919433594,   -67.099365234375,   -317.60797119140625,   -175.90196228027344,   -491.93121337890625,   214.3858642578125,   184.5579071044922,   346.4012756347656,   -151.8809051513672,   431.6130676269531,   -299.4017028808594,   184.5579071044922,   184.5579071044922,   241.29026794433594],  
'y': [-40.87070846557617,   245.00514221191406,   43.07831954956055,   -458.2991638183594,   270.4497985839844,   -453.2981262207031,   -439.6551513671875,   -206.3104248046875,   205.25787353515625,   -58.520164489746094,   43.07831954956055,   -182.91664123535156,   -458.2991638183594,   19.559282302856445,   -281.3316650390625,   103.6922378540039,   280.2445373535156,   -458.2991638183594,   -458.2991638183594,   -113.96920776367188]})
```

Comment: like stated [in the doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html#matplotlib-pyplot-scatter), you gan give the color to `ax.scatter`, have you tried this?

Comment: and please provide a minimal working example of your data ;-)

Comment: I have over 50 clusters sometimes, I don't wish to manually assign a color to each (like in my colors example)

Comment: you don't have to give them all manually, you can also give them a [cmap](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap)

Comment: @NicoAlbers I've added 20 lines of data as a data example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use [`df.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) syntax for comfortable reasons, but should be (nearly) the same as ax.scatter.

Okay, so using your example data, you can [specify a cmap like described in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap) :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['News',   'Hobbies & Interests',   'Arts & Entertainment',   'Internal Use',   'Business',   'Internal Use',   'Internal Use',   'Ad Impression Fraud',   'Arts & Entertainment',   'Adult Content',   'Arts & Entertainment',   'Internal Use',   'Internal Use',   'Reference',   'News',   'Shopping',   'Food & Drink',   'Internal Use',   'Internal Use',   'Reference'],  
'x': [-95.44078826904297,   127.71454620361328,   -491.93121337890625,   184.5579071044922,   -191.46273803710938,   95.22545623779297,   272.2229919433594,   -67.099365234375,   -317.60797119140625,   -175.90196228027344,   -491.93121337890625,   214.3858642578125,   184.5579071044922,   346.4012756347656,   -151.8809051513672,   431.6130676269531,   -299.4017028808594,   184.5579071044922,   184.5579071044922,   241.29026794433594],  
'y': [-40.87070846557617,   245.00514221191406,   43.07831954956055,   -458.2991638183594,   270.4497985839844,   -453.2981262207031,   -439.6551513671875,   -206.3104248046875,   205.25787353515625,   -58.520164489746094,   43.07831954956055,   -182.91664123535156,   -458.2991638183594,   19.559282302856445,   -281.3316650390625,   103.6922378540039,   280.2445373535156,   -458.2991638183594,   -458.2991638183594,   -113.96920776367188]})

df['col'] = df.c.astype('category').cat.codes

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', df.c.nunique())
ax = df.plot.scatter(
    x='x',y='y', c='col',
    cmap=cmap
)
plt.show()
```

Here `get_cmap` takes a cmap name (You can find the names of various maps on [this example page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)) and

> an integer giving the number of entries desired in the lookup table,

The above code results in the following: 
[image]

If you want to add your annotations and suppress the colorbar, use:

```
ax = df.plot.scatter(
    x='x',y='y', c='col',
    cmap=cmap, colorbar=False
)
for i, txt in enumerate(df['c'].tolist()):
    ax.annotate(txt, (df.x[i], df.y[i]))
plt.show()
```

And get the following: 
[image]

Hint: Use the "s" param in `plt.scatter(x,y,s=None, c=None, **kwds)` to change the size if this is too small.

Comment: You're welcome! :-) you can pass params which you would've passed to figure, so use `figsize=(20,20)` or similar if you want that bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, combining the two methods also solved it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(20,20)
x = df['x'].tolist()
y = df['y'].tolist()
ax.scatter(x, y)
for i, txt in enumerate(data['c'].tolist()):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))
for c in np.unique(data['c'].tolist()):
    df = tsne_df[data['c'].isin([c])]
    plt.plot(data['x'].tolist(),data['y'].tolist(),'o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This may work, but I wouldn't recommend using this, it is hard to read/understand, and probably only works because of "overwriting" some points, so you double up the creation of points and therefore doubling up the work for matplotlib. (btw, you assign to `df`, but never use it there)